# Delphi COM Server, "GetFunctionPointerForDelegate" callbacks : synchronize?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, callback, com, interop

Application is built around a stand-alone application using in-process COM servers as plugins. A communication plugin is interfaced with a C# layer through interop and after calling an C# async connection method (itself using C# thread) "GetFunctionPointerForDelegate" is used to notify status changed to Delphi COM server.

- Stand-alone application (Delphi .exe)

  - In-process COM server (Delphi .dll/regsvr32)

    - C# interop communication layer (C# .dll assemblies/regasm)

It appears distinct threadIDs are callbacking Delphi COM server through callback pointers after logging threadID received by callback methods. As these callbacks are received asynchronously (afaik), i was wondering if it needs to :

a) process them directly when fired (in calling thread context?) :

```
Application.mainthreadID
 - COM Server threadId
    - callback (threadId=1) : callback processing...
    - callback (threadId=2) : callback processing...
```

b) dispatch these callbacks to COM server mainthread (to process them in COM server thread context) :

```
Application.mainthreadID
 - COM Server threadId
     - custom dynamic "WndProc"
        - callback (threadId=1) : Dispatch/PostMessage...
        - callback (threadId=2) : Dispatch/PostMessage...
```

In order to dispatch these C# callbacks to COM server mainthread, a window subclassing is dynamically created  (within COM server) with a custom "WndProc" receiving custom WM_XXX dispatched messages :

```
TFooCOMServer.CallbackEntryPoint1(...)
 PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CUSTOM_CALLBACK1, wParam, lParam);

TFooCOMServer.CustonWndProc( Msg : TMesssage);
 ...
  Case Msg.message of
    WM_CUSTOM_CALLBACK1 : OnCustomCallBack(param1,param2);
     ...
  end;
```

My questions about this COM/multi-thread application pattern are :

- Does this dispatcher makes sens ? Does it worth the while to synchronize through "WndProc" process message callbacks processing ?
- If yes, how callback method parameters should be marshalled from callback entry point to "WndProc" dispatcher target ? In case of interface parameter type (dispatched through PostMessage "lParam or wParam" integer), how to dispatch safely this interface pointer and what about interface refcounting/life cycle, should i increment or marshall (to "WndProc" thread) these interface pointers ?

Thanks in advance for your help on this subject.

Comment: 1. "GetFunctionPointerForDelegate" (without "synchronize" function used) : related threading issues in order to manage synchronization in the main thread. 
- Does a sub-classing "WndProc" style dispatcher is necessary/reliable (to handle callbacks in a single thread context) ?

2. STA/MTA threading issues with input interface pointer (from "GetFunctionPointerForDelegate" callback) : How to send thread interface pointer to main thread receiver/processing ? 
- Does PostMessage standart pointer parameter is ok to provide interface pointer to the main thread ? 

Thank you for your opinion.